# Help with an interesting reciprocal prime sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, prime-numbers

How can you evaluate $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{\sum (n)} \right)$ where $\sum (n)$ is the sum of the first $n$ prime numbers? I was able to find numerical bounds by running code to give a lower bound of $1.02345$, and I found an upper bound by taking the reciprocal of the Prime Sum Function approximation $\frac{\ln(n)\cdot n^2}{2}$ and evaluating a sum from there, but I would like to figure out how to evaluate this exactly.

Comment: Most randomly chosen infinite series cannot be evaluated in closed form. I don't see any reason why there would be a closed form for this series.

Comment: Thank you, that is very interesting. However, as this sum isn't random and sums the primes, shouldn't there be a closed form? I'm curious:)

Comment: Most sums don't have closed form.

Answer (score 1):

*Exactly* would be very difficult.

You want to compute $$S=\sum_{n = 1}^\infty  \frac{1}{a_n} \qquad \text{where} \qquad a_n=\sum _{i=1}^n p_i$$ What I should do it to write it as
$$S=\sum_{n = 1}^p \frac{1}{a_n}+\sum_{n = p+1}^\infty  \frac{1}{a_n}$$

Concerning
$$s_p=\sum_{n = 1}^p \frac{1}{a_n}$$ they form the sequence
$$\left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{10},\frac{4}{5},\frac{73}{85},\frac{2129}{2380},\frac
   {89669}{97580},\frac{2649191}{2829820},\frac{29545361}{31128020},\frac{7464160
   3}{77820050}\right\}$$ For the second summation, I should use as an approximation of $a_n$
$$\frac{n^2}{2}\left[\ln n + \ln\ln n - \frac{3}{2} + \frac{\ln\ln n}{\ln n} - \frac{5}{2\ln n} - \frac{\ln^2\ln n}{2\ln^2 n} + \frac{7\ln\ln n}{2\ln^2 n} - \frac{29}{4\ln^2 n} + \cdots\right]$$ as proposed by Sinha in $2011$.